# Getting the file data of a PDF contained in an Embed tag

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm working on a small electron app to manage editable character sheet pdfs. I'm currently trying to implement saving the pdf via hotkey, as well as autosaving.

I'm displaying said sheets using an html <embed> tag like so:

```
<embed src="../sheets/page.pdf">
```

To save the file, given these PDFs have editable fields, I need to pull the file data from the embed in its current state. Is getting this data possible, and if so, how would I go about doing it?

Thank you.